# this wait/notify code has abnormal performance

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, wait, notify

look the java wait/notify code. I think, will not print false.
But, when I run the code, print false somtime.
Is it java bug?

```java
public class TestThread {

    public static volatile String lock = "111";
    public static volatile AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        synchronized (lock) {
                            flag.compareAndSet(true, false);
                            lock.wait();
                            if (!flag.get()) {
                                System.out.println(flag.get());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        flag.compareAndSet(false, true);
                        lock.notify();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

console result:
false
false
false

Comment: Waiting threads can be woken up without you calling `notify`. Check the [API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--): "As in the one argument version, interrupts and spurious wakeups are possible, and this method should always be used in a loop".

Comment: thank you for your comment, i agree it....

Comment: 'Abnormal performance' compared to what norm?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for such a behavior is called *spurious wakeup*.

Thread may stop waiting and continue it's execution **without** `notify()` call. This is a [spurious wakeup](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup) - a mechanism of operation system thread scheduler.

That's why you always check some condition before calling `wait()` and set it explicitly before calling `notify()`. Do not use `notify()` itself as a guarantee of a job being done.

Example:

Thread 1

```
synchronized (lock) {
    ...
    while (!condition) {
        lock.wait();
    }
    ...
}
```

Thread 2

```
synchronized (lock) {
    condition = true;
    lock.notify();
}
```